# Probability of successful conversion of an IC call?

Tags: probability

I have a practical probability question. We have IC calls coming in from customers which passes through many stages like Inquiry, Lead, Opportunity, Quotation and Sales Order (Success). At each incremental stage there is more chance of converting the call to Sales Order. How do I find the probability of success for all the IC calls and hence how many machines I need to produce based on that information?

Comment: Seems like the problem behind is an inventory problem which asking what is the optimal stocking rules. So yes first you consider to estimate the sales distribution. You may start with a very crude point estimate of sales  which is the proportion of call to sales (estimated via historical data) and then multiply by the incoming call now. Of course you can somehow improve the estimate by considering the time to produce, and the conversion rate to further stages etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate the proportions from your data. Let's say you are trying to estimate the proportion of IC calls resulting in a sale.

Calculate $\hat{p} = \frac{\text{number of sales}}{\text{number of IC calls}}$

where $\hat{p}$ is an estimator of $p$, the true value of the proportion. You want to find a confidence interval for this proportion, which is

$$ \hat{p} \pm z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}} $$ where $z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ is obtained from this table

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Types_of_tables

with $\alpha =$ how large you want this confidence interval to be and $n =$ sample size, in this case number of IC calls. For example, let say from your data you determine that $200$ calls resulted in $50$ sales and you want a $90\%$ confidence interval for this estimation, then

$\hat{p} = \frac{50}{200} = 0.25$

$\alpha = 0.9$ , so that $\frac{\alpha}{2} = 0.45 $. Now find $0.45$ in the table above which you will see is somewhere close to the row $1.6$ and column $+0.04$, i.e. $z_{0.45}\approx 1.64$.

You can also get the $z$ value in EXCEL using this formula:

=-NORM.S.INV((1-$\alpha)/2$)

Your interval is then $$ 0.25 \pm 1.64\sqrt{\frac{0.25*0.75}{200}} \approx [ 0.199 , 0.3  ] $$

This is saying that you are $90\%$ confident that the true proportion of IC calls resulting in sales is somewhere between $19.9\%$ and $30\%$.

The next step is to estimate the mean number of IC calls for the month. This can be a bit more involved, especially if you have seasonality, upward or downward trends etc. You have to graph your monthly numbers in Excel for example to get an idea, but you would have to get some sort of estimate of the mean number of calls for a particular month. Then you can use the estimator of the mean number of IC calls, multiplied by the limits of the interval of the proportion estimator to get an estimate of the sales for the month.

Using the above you can estimate for example, proportion of calls leading to Inquiry, proportion of Quotations leading to Sales etc.